# MapBox pod installation failure

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, mapbox

**MapBox pod installation issues**

Hi friend , i researched on [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-navigation-ios/navigation/0.16.2/) implementation , basically for in app navigation but unable to install pod. please help me.

[image: When i am install the pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.16 the issue has come.]

[image: After add 'use_framework' , i am able to install but again issues come with swift2.x tag]

Comment: What's your podfile?  What version of MapBox did you install? Because it says: "The Mapbox Navigation SDK and Core Navigation are compatible with applications written in Swift 4 or Objective-C in Xcode 9.0. The Mapbox Navigation framework runs on iOS 9.0 and above, while the Core Navigation framework runs on iOS 8.0 and above." So it should be okay.

Comment: This pod is **'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.16'**  using to install.

Comment: First remove `pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.16'` and install pod. Then again add `pod 'MapboxNavigation'` and install pod. Due MapboxNavigation version 0.16 contains code with swift 2.0 and you are using XCode 9.0 which does not support swift 2.0.

Comment: @PaulMarshal..Thanks to reply me. we have already try with **'MapboxNavigation'**

Comment: Show your whole podfile.

Comment: @Magnas..Here is the pod ** 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.16'**  . I follow the link https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-navigation-ios/navigation/0.16.2/

Comment: @PaulMarshal Same issues are at the GitHub Here.https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/issues/253

Comment: Please see the another bug at the MapBox Navigation.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098560/mapbox-navigation-pod-unable-to-install-with-objectivec-where-i-am-using-xcode-9

Comment: Unfortunately , i solved the issues by the Carthage. Thanks to Mapbox