# MapBox navigation pod unable to install with ObjectiveC where i am using Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, navigation, mapbox

**we are unable to install pod for mapbox navigation. Please help me**

1. we are follow the [mapbox navigation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-navigation-ios/navigation/0.16.2/) documentation step by step . **We are successfully install the pod 'MapboxNavigation' When i am using swift language with Xcode 9.2**
2. But when we go through language ObjectiveC with same Xcode9.2 version, we are unable to install the pod.. the issues are given in the screen shoot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Github project](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios), MapBox supports Xcode 9 and swift 4, maybe the website documentation is outdated.

Comment: We have no problem with MapBox supports Xcode 9 and swift 4. its ok with me. problem having when use objective c language with Xcode 9 or above version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mapbox i got it solution , we can go through the **Carthage** ,we have no problem with objective c in xcode 9 . Thanks.